# Wrong return value of function (Probably wrong string "type"?)

Tags: ios, xcode, string, function

I got a function which should return an `int`value.

```
- (int)function:(NSString *)input
{
 if (input == @"test1")
    {
        return 0;  
    }
 if (input == @"test2")
    {
        return 1;  
    }
 if (input == @"test3")
    {
        return 2;  
    }
 else
{
    return 3;
}
}
```

Here I call the function:

```
[self function:self.detailItem.type]
```

The debugger shows `input   __NSCFString *  0x6b9a0b0` and returns any `29938idontknow`value.

If I call `[self function:@"test1"]` everything works fine.

The `detailItem`is type of `TV`which is a `NSManagedObject`with the attribute `type` defined as `string`. Should be a problem with the `string`-types?

Thank you!

Comment: Try [input isEqualToString:"xxx"] to compare strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should compare NSString like this :

```
if ([input isEqualToString:@"test1"])
{
    // Some code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that self.detailItem.type is an NSString:

```
if ([self.detailItem.type isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
```

before calling

```
[self function:self.detailItem.type]
```

and compare strings like this

```
[input isEqualToString:@"test1"];
```

you are currently comparing memory addresses, which in this case will be always different, you should be comparing the strings they contain.